# WPF - Combo Box with Items that include a Button

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I have a ComboBox control in a window. I am reading the items that comprise the ComboBox at runtime from an XML file. What I would like to do is to include a Button object with each item so that if the user clicks the button, I can take appropriate action based on the item associated with the button. It might look something like this when the user drops down the list:

```
Item 1         [Button]
Another Item   [Button]
Item 3         [Button]
```

I don't have enough experience with WPF to know if this is possible, but a co-worker said it should be doable. Has anyone done this, or know how it might be done? Keep in mind the ComboBox control is created via XAML but the items are created at runtime.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="MyComboBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <Label Content="{Binding}" Width="100" />
                        <Button Grid.Column="1">Do Something</Button>
                    </Grid>

                </DataTemplate>
            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ComboBox>
```

And in the code behind, I used a simple list of strings:

```
List<String> strings = new List<string>();

strings.Add("Item 1");
strings.Add("Another Item");
strings.Add("Item 3");

MyComboBox.ItemsSource = strings;
```

And this is what it looked like:

[image]

**EDIT:** Here is a resource on how to add a grid to a ComboBox drop down (this goes beyond the scope of an SO answer):

http://www.eggheadcafe.com/tutorials/aspnet/e8585e81-34c8-4808-ae3e-b8b35d738842/wpf-datagrid-as-combobox.aspx

Comment: @RQDQ - Thank you. Where would this block of XAML code go with respect to my main .XAML file?

Comment: In this example, I just plopped it in the middle of my Window2.xaml file (as a child of the <grid> tag).  Note that you could also separate the DataTemplate into a resource, but it's not necessary.

Comment: @RQDQ - Sort of. I would really like the buttons to be flush right, regardless of the width of the first column (100 in your example).

Comment: @Randy - I added a link to a resource that goes into a much more complicated template that looks like it might do what you need.