# How to add a new item button to a dropdownlist using c# for Winforms API

Tags: c#, winforms, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown list and I populate it programmatically with a dataset pulled from a database.

What I like to do is add an option to act like a button "  " button. when it is clicked a user is navigated to a different form.

something like this
 (screenshot before clicking on the drop-down menu)
[image]

(screenshot to show the option like a button "  "

[image]

This is the code that I am using to populate the menu

```
private void InventoryAdd_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    InputDepartment.Items.Clear();
    InputVendors.Items.Clear();

    //populate the Departments menu
    dbConnetion db = new dbConnetion();

    string sql =  " SELECT departmentName, departmentID "
                + " FROM departments "
                + " WHERE status = 'active' ";

    InputDepartment.Items.Clear();
    var deptSource = new List<ComboItem>();

    deptSource.Add(new ComboItem { ID = -1, Text = "Select a Department" });
    deptSource.Add(new ComboItem { ID = 0, Text = " < Add New> " });

    foreach (var item in db.getData(sql, null, r => new ComboItem()
                                    {

                                        ID = Convert.ToInt32(r["departmentID"]),
                                        Text = r["departmentName"].ToString()
                                    })
    )
    {
        deptSource.Add(item);

    };

    InputDepartment.DataSource = deptSource;

}



//This generic class will help setting an id and a text for a comboItem
class ComboItem
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string Val1 { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Text;
    }
}
```

This is my getData Method
        // query the data base

```
public IEnumerable<T> getData<T>(string query, List<MySqlParameter> pars, Func<IDataRecord, T> transform)
{
    using (var conn = new MySqlConnection(conn_string))
    using (var cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, conn))
    {
        if (pars != null)
        {
            foreach (MySqlParameter p in pars)
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Add(p);
            }
        }

        conn.Open();

        using (var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {

            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                yield return transform(rdr);
            }
        }

        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: I just updated my question. It is ageneric class will help setting an id and a text for a comboItem

Comment: Do you have to create the ComboItem twice? once in foreach selector, than again in the body of that same loop?

Comment: I am not very sure if there is a better approach to this. I am new to c# so I am open for better method. I have added the code behind getData method in case you want to review that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
deptSource.Add(new ComboItem { ID = i.ID, Text = i.Text });
```

use

```
deptSource.Add(i);
```

as i already is a ComboItem. Also, if your getData returns IEnumerable, that might be costly, so use.

```
foreach (var i in db.getData(sql, null, r => new ComboItem()
    {
         ID = Convert.ToInt32(r["departmentID"]),
         Text = r["departmentName"].ToString()
     }).ToList()
```

or even simpler:

```
deptSource.AddRange( db.getData(sql, null, r => new ComboItem()
    {
         ID = Convert.ToInt32(r["departmentID"]),
         Text = r["departmentName"].ToString()
     }) );
```

Finally, you need to hook up an event to:

```
protected override void OnSelectedValueChanged( EventArgs e )
```

Then you can check if the new value is 0 and perform your new item addition elsewhere.

**UPDATE**

I don't believe the standard ComboBox supports adding a button. There are 3rd party tools, which do. WPF also does.

Comment: thank you so much for making the code a lot more shorted +1 :) But why would I use `OnSelectedValueChanged`? and how would I add an option as a button "my original question?" I am trying to replace the `deptSource.Add(new ComboItem { ID = 0, Text = " < Add New> " });` with a buttom item type. not an option but a button as you can see in the screenshots

Comment: what is WPF? I am using Telerik RadDropDownList

Comment: WPF === Windows Presentation Foundation. If you use Telerik, you might be able to fake the look you are looking for using MultiColumnComboxBox, as it is using a RadGridView implementation. But I;d rethink the UX before I'd try faking it. Or I'd recommend going to WPF.

Comment: http://our.componentone.com/2006/02/14/implementing-custom-dropdown-controls/ These guys can do whatever you want with a ComboBox.

Comment: And with WPF the sky is the limit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4855892/wpf-combo-box-with-items-that-include-a-button and http://www.howdoicode.net/2012/07/wpf-customizing-combobox.html